# How is the impact of analytics steering user newsfeed measured on a national basis in the US?

Tags: media, social-media

Technology is a double edged sword: its implementation and usage determines outcomes, be it good, bad and ugly.  That being said, the rise of the analytic algorithms to select news content **for an individual** is an innovation that can shape perspectives & outcomes.

How is the effect of steering analytics, **which selects news-content for readers** on a per user basis, measured on a national basis in the United States? or any large nation state?

Comment: Key words for you: "echo chambers" and "filter bubbles". But the effect of steering is going to be hard to separate from that of sharing... unless google or facebook publishes a study on this, which I doubt they will.

Comment: What I can tell you is that slightly more than half of users interviewed in a study were unaware that Facebook uses steering, i.e. they thought sharing was all that mattered. https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/may/22/social-media-election-facebook-filter-bubbles

Comment: Some have called for regulation of such (and other) algorithms (of public interest): https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2747994